# Trying to have multiple input elements

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-functional-component

But when i use handle input change function it erases the entire object and replaces it with one property

Also If someone can help me reset the form data?  because I'm setting state to the initial state value but the text fields arent erasing.

```
const initialState = {
  name: '',
  number: '',
  message: '',
  email: '',
  messageSent: false,
};

//State After typingState
{email: "2"}
```

I was using a class-based component and it was working fine I switched over and now I am getting one property on submit instead of 4
 I would like for the handle change to change a particular property and not the entire object 
stepped away from react for a while an d not sure what to google fo this fix. Tried
Handling Multiple inputs Functional Components React etc..

```
 let handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    setstate({
      [name]: value,
    });
  }
    return (
      <section
        id="contact-form"
        className={
         GrayBg === true
            ? 'contact-form-area_3'
            : 'contact-form-area_3  contact-page-version'
        }
      >
        <div className="container">
          <div className="section-title mb45 headline text-center">
            <span className="subtitle text-uppercase">Send us a message</span>
            <h2>
              Send Us A<span> Message.</span>
            </h2>
          </div>

          <div className="contact_third_form">
            <form
              className="contact_form"
              encType="multipart/form-data"
              onSubmit={ sendEmail}
            >
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-4">
                  <div className="contact-info">
                    <input
                      className="name"
                      name="name"
                      type="text"
                      value={state.value}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      placeholder="Your Name."
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                  <div className="contact-info">
                    <input
                      className="email"
                      name="email"
                      type="email"
                      value={state.value}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      placeholder="Your Email"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                  <div className="contact-info">
                    <input
                      className="number"
                      name="number"
                      type="number"
                      value={state.value}
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      placeholder="Phone Number"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <textarea
                name="message"
                placeholder="Message."
                value={state.value}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              ></textarea>
              <div className="nws-button text-center  gradient-bg text-uppercase">
                <button id="contact-button" type="submit">
                  {state.messageSent ? 'Sent!' : 'Send'}{' '}
                  <i
                    className={
                      state.messageSent
                        ? 'fas fa-check'
                        : 'fas fa-caret-right'
                    }
                  ></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**State updates are not merged with hooks** unlike in class components, you need to do so yourself.

Update your state using a functional approach to setState and by spreading the rest of the values within the returned object like

```
setstate(prev => ({
  ...prev,
  [name]: value,
}));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea where to look for this. One More question do I clear the fields the same way? because the state is changing but the text isn't clearing.

Comment: Yes you will need to provide the entire updated object to setstate

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example?

Comment: `setstate({
  name: '',
  number: '',
  message: '',
  email: '',
  messageSent: false,
})`

Comment: setstate((prev) => ({
              ...prev,
              ...initialState
            }));
          }, 3000);

Comment: Yes the state is changing fine but the text isn't disappearing from the fields

Comment: That is because no input is controlled as of now. They should use value like `value={state.number}` and so on.

Comment: Bro thank you so much you dont know how long I've been googling! Cheers and be safe

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)